# Find in which country each point-coordinate belongs to

Tags: r, geolocation, maps

I have a data frame with lat/lon coordinates:

```
head(COORD)
   LAT   LON 
1  69.34 16.17  
2  69.20 17.92   
3  69.59 17.87 
4  69.17 18.52  
5  69.42 18.95 
6  69.22 18.91
```

I would like to to retrieve the country name of each point and add it as a third column.
Maybe using `which` in combination with `map` to retrieve in which polygon the points are but I was not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using map.where()

```
library(maps)

COORD$Country <- map.where(database="world", COORD$LON, COORD$LAT)
```

Comment: you may want to specify which package the `map.where` function is in.