# Equivelent of maps package within R

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a dataset that has 3 Million+ Rows, part of that dataset contains Latitude and Longitude coordinates and I need to run a check against those co-ordinates, bring back the country and then compare that country against the country already in the dataset.

The suggestion to use the maps package in an older post ([Fastest way to determine COUNTRY from millions of GPS coordinates [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910965/fastest-way-to-determine-country-from-millions-of-gps-coordinates-r)) is brilliant, however that package leaves me with around 190,000 NA values even though the coordinates are 100% valid (I have checked them in other online services).

Example of some entries that should have a match, but do not match:

LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
1.3346258   51.96007
1.34711853  51.96614
1.33469456  51.95923
1.21408338  52.94419
1.74703244  52.47744
1.30218822  52.9191

So, what I need is for a package like maps that has all of the geocodes (world wide).

Most of the alternatives I have found so far are either paid alternatives or have search limits.

Even if I run using my existing code first and then run those that result in NA and rejoin would do.

Example of my code, should anyone need it is `Latest[, COUNTRY := map.where(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE)]`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that, at this time, there is no alternative world wide like maps package.